# Open a specific tab with url value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, tabs

I am Using a Wordpress, and I would like users to open a specific tab directly from a link in the navbar. So I want to disable the default active tab (15 Nov) and activate the tab with the value in url.

I have tried domain.com/agenda/#16-nov but it did not work!
Can anyone advise how this is done?

```
<ul class="scheduleday_wrapper tab">
   <li data-tab="15-nov" class="scheduleday_title active">
      <div class="scheduleday_title_content">
         <h4 style="">15 Nov</h4>
      </div>
      <br class="clear">
   </li>
   <li data-tab="16-nov" class="scheduleday_title">
      <div class="scheduleday_title_content">
         <h4 style="">16 Nov</h4>
      </div>
      <br class="clear">
   </li>
   <li data-tab="17-nov" class="scheduleday_title">
      <div class="scheduleday_title_content">
         <h4 style="">17 Nov</h4>
      </div>
      <br class="clear">
   </li>
</ul>
```

And here the class code of content:

```
<ul id="15-nov" class="scheduleday_wrapper themeborder tab_content"></ul>
<ul id="16-nov" class="scheduleday_wrapper themeborder tab_content hide"></ul>
<ul id="17-nov" class="scheduleday_wrapper themeborder tab_content hide"></ul>
```

Comment: Please paste code as-is, not images of it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

A *Link* could be an anchor tag `<a href="Absolute_or_Relative_URL">Link</a>`, something that simulates anchor behavior (e.g. using a JavaScript routing library), a clickable element with an Event Listener, etc.. It is not clear if you *must* use URL hashes (/agenda/**#16-nov**), or if they are just something you experimented with. If you must use URL hashes (e.g. because a request must go the server first for processing before re-rendering the page), I can provide another solution.

The JavaScript below uses clickable elements (your `<li class="scheduleday_title"/>` tabs) to trigger event listeners. It assumes one tab is always active. The function `updateActiveStatus` is called within the tab event listener with the selected date as its argument in the format `17-nov`.

You can make adjustments and test them with [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kofeigen/obc48ahL/).

### updateActiveStatus function

```js
/**
 * Update the active state of tab elements and the hide state of content elements.
 *
 * @param {string} currentDate - Date from the clicked tab.
 *
 */
function updateActiveStatus (currentDate) {
  // currentDate: e.g. 17-nov
  let previousTabElement = document.querySelector('.active');

  if (previousTabElement != null) {
    previousTabElement.classList.remove('active');

    // Hide all content elements.
    let contentElements = document.querySelectorAll('.content .scheduleday_wrapper');
    for (let contentElement of contentElements) {
      contentElement.classList.add('hide');
    }

    // Activate the new tabElement and show the new content element.
    let tabElements = document.querySelectorAll('.scheduleday_title');
    for (let tabElement of tabElements) {
      if (tabElement.dataset.tab == currentDate) {
        tabElement.classList.add('active');

        let contentElement = document.getElementById(currentDate);
        contentElement.classList.remove('hide');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Add Event Listeners

```js
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.scheduleday_title');

for (let tab of tabs) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function() {
    updateActiveStatus(tab.dataset.tab);
  });
}
```